# Django for loop from custom minimum and maximum value with user specific forloop counter

Tags: django, for-loop

I have a minimum, maximum and a scale/difference value of a price. How can I show all available price range, in Django template.

```
Eg: minimum price- 20
maximum price - 36
price scale - 4
```

Excpected Result

```
Width - 20, 24, 28, 32 and 36
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a [simple inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) to do this (giving you control over the template):

Tag: **myapp/templatetags/range_tags.py**:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('my_app/my_template.html')
def range(min, max, step):
    return { "result": range(min, max, step )}
```

Inclusion Template: **templates/my_app/my_template.html**:

```
{% for val in result %}
     {{ val }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% else %} and {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Rendering Template:

```
{% load range_tags %}
{% range min max step %}
```

Comment: small mistake of my teacher -> {{ val }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% else %} and {% endif %}

Comment: Cool, I've fixed that now.